# Severe lagging of Gentoo terminal after fresh installation

Tags: terminal, gentoo

I have just freshly installed the Gentoo via the latest Minimal installation CD released on January 02, 2022 (OpenRC Stage3). I have installed Gentoo several times before. But none of the time I encountered severe lagging of the terminal after completion of installation. By lagging, I mean, whenever I type none of the text is displayed. When I choose Quit in VirtualBox, the pop-up of what I want to do (i.e. Save machine state, Poweroff, etc.) comes and suddenly, the text I typed appears. Before that, no text appears. While `emerging`, the terminal doesn't update. I should click on Quit every time I want to see the progress. It has never happened to me before.

NOTE: By `terminal`, I mean right after the installation completion process. Not any new terminal installed. Just the whole installation process according to AMD64 Handbook is complete. Just rebooted the system and this problem arises

Since I am running Gentoo as a guest, like all the previous times before, I made sure that the Kernel is made to support Gentoo as a guest as given in the [docs](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/VirtualBox). I have always been performing the same steps. I also made sure to check the docs for any updates so that I could modify them accordingly.

The profile I chose is just the stable `default/linux/amd64/17.1 (stable)`

I also gave it plenty of RAM and storage (`11256 MB` and `1 TB` respectively)

The following are the disks

`/dev/sda1` : EFI boot partition : `256 MB` : `VFAT`

`/dev/sda2` : Swap : `8 GB`

`/dev/sda3` : Linux filesystem : `1015.75 GB` : `ext4`

Kernel version: `5.15.11`

GRUB didn't report any error and I did `grub-install` for `x86_64-efi` system

I also installed the `initramfs` (as always)

What could be the reason for this lagging? Any solutions for this?

Comment: Could you post your kernel logs ?

Comment: Could you be more precise regarding your "after completion of installation". Where about are you in the installation process. (You can refer to handbook section)

Comment: That doesn’t sound like lag. It sounds like the video driver/setup being used by Linux is incompatible with how VirtualBox works (and would be unlikely to happen in the same way if you used different virtualization software or installed it on a real machine). Try building a kernel without framebuffer drivers or with different ones and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @MC68020 Actually, all the sections in the handbook are complete. 
[Configuring the Bootloader] (https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Handbook:AMD64/Installation/Bootloader)
Even after the above section `Rebooting the system` (entering into Finalizing), it started to lag. I managed to complete the Finalizing section too. This is what I meant by completing the installation

Comment: Agreeing with @binki analysis, I nevertheless strongly discourage to follow his advice consisting in building the kernel without framebuffer drivers. Contrarily, I would advise to make sure that the "simple framebuffer support" is ensured. For the complete set of kernel settings for a gentoo guest under virtualbox, please read https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/VirtualBox

Comment: @MC68020 Yes. That's what I did too. I did follow the docs for Gentoo guests in Virtualbox. I ensured if only the settings stated are enabled